# Does breezesharp work with NHibernate metadata?

Tags: breeze, breeze-sharp

we've been using breeze for a long time and now I'm trying to access an existing webapi controller with a breezesharp client. Our controller is using NHibernate for data access.
On `FetchMetadata` the application throws an object reference not set exception on that line(24)
`_schema = json["schema"];` in CsdlMetadataProcessor.
If I look at our metadata there is no schema node.
Am i missing something? Is there a different configuration for NHibernate?

edit: I also tried to export my metadata and import it with ImportMetadata on the metadatastore but it throws another exception when creating the clr type...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this was a bug and will be fixed in the next version of breeze-sharp, out later this week.

Comment: I pulled the latest version: now it breaks when creating clr types based on structuraltypes

Comment: What error are you getting? I cannot repro your issue, can you also try getting the latest breeze.server.net from GitHub. I will be creating Nuget packages for these later this week or early next.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

it's my fault. The bug with the NHibernate metadata has been fixed but my entities doesn't inherit from `BaseEntity`. We are heavily using breeze with a SPA and I was happy to reuse my existing code with a .net client but deriving my model entities from the `BaseEntity` class of Breeze is not an option.

Would it be possible to use reflection.emit or Castle DynamicProxy to create proxies of the model on the fly? That way the model could stay without any inheritance.

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300209/breeze-why-inheriting-from-breeze-sharp-baseentity